# Front Page server extensions for IIS 8

Tags: iis-8

I need Front Page server extensions for IIS 8 , provide a link to me please, as I can't create websites on Visual Studio 2012 by virtual servers setting HTTP Web Location. Also I am unable to run an .ASP and .HTML website made on Notepad Virtually. 
Front Page Server Extensions fr IIS 8 Needed badly.

Comment: http://www.rtr.com/fpse/Win2008R2/index.htm You will have to contact Ready To Run